# Having issues with .gitmodules in getting my Hugo Site onto github pages

Tags: github, git-submodules, hugo

So I managed to create a static webpage using the Hugo Framework and the After-Dark theme (https://after-dark.habd.as). I uploaded my site to my repository (https://github.com/Lord-Left/Lord-Left.github.io) but when I try to build the site, I get the following error:

> Your site is having problems building: The submodule public was not
>   properly initialized with a .gitmodules file. For more information,
>   see
>   https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-missing-submodule/.

This is the link to my submodule file (located in root). I created it by tinkering with it, is it correct?

https://github.com/Lord-Left/Lord-Left.github.io/blob/master/.gitmodules

Answer (score 4):

In you `.gitmodules`, you say

```
[submodule "after-dark"]
path = after-dark
url = https://git.habd.as/comfusion/after-dark
```

While the following works for me:

```
[submodule "themes/beautifulhugo"]
path = themes/beautifulhugo
url = https://github.com/halogenica/beautifulhugo
```

Looks like you are just missing the `themes/` part that would point correctly to a subfolder.